# The concept of the creation of a trapdoor in NP-complete or NP-hard problems

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, cryptography, np-complete

I am reading the book [*An Introduction to Mathematical Cryptography*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4939-1711-2). In its chapter 7, there is the following statement:

> In real world scenarios, cryptosystems based on NP-hard or NP-complete problems tend to rely on particular subclass of problems either to achieve efficiency or to allow the creation of a trapdoor.

**Questions:**

Is is possible to explain what does it mean the phrase "*to allow the creation of a trapdoor*"?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) is a case where you can see it: a genral knapsack problem is NP-hard and worst-case NP-complete, but in developing the cryptosystem we must be able to mask an easily solvable instance to look like a hard one, so the problems that were used were easy ones (super-increasing) then modified by a modular multiplication and modular reduction to make them look like "random" instances (this is the [Merkle-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Hellman_knapsack_cryptosystem) variant). But if you knew the original problem plus the modifications (this is the trapdoor) solving them would be easy. So choosing *special* problems allowed for a trapdoor (extra info that allows the decryption algorithm) to exist. This kind of example is what the writer of that chapter had in mind, probably.